Have double border left and right css
I would like my double border with one line shorter than the other left and right.
the left is current only 1 line missing the smaller one


   .double-border {
  --b: 2px; /* thickness */
  --c: #3CD5AF;
  
  height: 100%;
  border-right: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  border-left: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  background: linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) right 10px bottom 0/var(--b) 50% no-repeat
}
 <div class="col-lg-8 double-border">
                            <h4>About the episode subhead lorem ipsum 1</h4>
                            <p>Nulla Lorem mollit cupidatat irure. Laborum magna nulla duis ullamco cillum dolor. Voluptate exercitation incididunt aliquip deserunt.</p>
                            <a hreff="">link</a></a>
                        </div>




Just use two background gradients.


.double-border {
  --b: 2px;
  /* thickness */
  --c: #3CD5AF;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  border-left: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  background: 
  linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) left 10px bottom 0/var(--b) 50% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) right 10px bottom 0/var(--b) 50% no-repeat
}

div {
  padding: 0 2em;
}
<div class="col-lg-8 double-border">
  <h4>About the episode subhead lorem ipsum 1</h4>
  <p>Nulla Lorem mollit cupidatat irure. Laborum magna nulla duis ullamco cillum dolor. Voluptate exercitation incididunt aliquip deserunt.</p>
  <a hreff="">link</a></a>
</div>




An optimized version


.double-border {
  --b: 2px;/* thickness */
  --c: #3CD5AF;
  
  border-inline: var(--b) solid var(--c);
  --g:10px bottom 0/var(--b) 50% no-repeat 
   linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0);
  background:left var(--g),right var(--g);
}

div {
  padding: 0 2em;
}
<div class="col-lg-8 double-border">
  <h4>About the episode subhead lorem ipsum 1</h4>
  <p>Nulla Lorem mollit cupidatat irure. Laborum magna nulla duis ullamco cillum dolor. Voluptate exercitation incididunt aliquip deserunt.</p>
  <a hreff="">link</a></a>
</div>



